# Dataset showing unexpected Data

Tags: c#, dataset

I have 2 `ListBoxes` and five `textBox`. In `ListBox_prod` i want to retrieve all product (from PRODUCT table) and in `Listbox_item` i want to retrieve all Items corresponding to the selected Product (from PRODITEM table) on form load event. All the products have more than 1 items associated with them. Problem is with the `Listbox_item` as it is showing only 1 item. But I want all items to be displayed in `Listbox_item` when a particulat product is selected.  `getData()` in class `DBCommands` actually causes the problem. Here's my code:

```
public partial class form_prodItems : Form
{       
       private DBCommands dBCommand;

     public form_prodItems()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBx_prod.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBx_prod_selValChange);
        listBx_item.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBx_item_selValChange);
    }
   private void form_prodItems_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     { 
        // ...
        refresh_listBx_prod("PRODUCT", this.listBx_prod, null, null);
        refresh_listBx_prod("PRODITEM", this.listBx_item, listBx_prod.ValueMember,   listBx_prod.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }

    private void listBx_item_selValChange(object sender, EventArgs e) // causing problem
    {
        if (listBx_item.SelectedValue != null)
            showPrice("PRODITEM", listBx_item.ValueMember, listBx_item.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }

    private void listBx_prod_selValChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(listBx_prod.SelectedValue != null)
           refresh_listBx_prod("PRODITEM", this.listBx_item, listBx_prod.ValueMember, listBx_prod.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }

    private void showPrice(string tblName,string where_column ,string where_val)
    {
        DataSet ds;
        ds = dBCommand.getData("select * from " + tblName + " WHERE " + where_column + " = '" + where_val + "'");
        DataRow col_val = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];

        txtBox_12oz.Text = col_val.ItemArray[3].ToString();
        txtBox_16oz.Text = col_val.ItemArray[4].ToString();
        txtBox_20oz.Text = col_val.ItemArray[5].ToString();
        txtBox_1lbs.Text = col_val.ItemArray[6].ToString();
        txtBox_2lbs.Text = col_val.ItemArray[7].ToString();
        //ds.Clear();
    }

    private void refresh_listBx_prod(string tblName, ListBox listBox, string where_column, string where_val)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dBCommand = new DBCommands();

        if (where_column == null)
        {
            ds = dBCommand.getData("SELECT * FROM " + tblName);
        }
        else
        {
            ds = dBCommand.getData("SELECT * FROM " + tblName + " WHERE " + where_column + " = " + where_val);
        }
        listBox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
     //   ds.Clear();
    }
}   


public class DBCommands
{
    private SqlConnection conn;
    private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
    private DataSet container;

    public DataSet getData(string selectCmd)
    {
        container.Clear();    // I guess something needs to be fixed here some where..
        conn = getConnection();
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectCmd, conn);
        dataAdapter.Fill(container);
        conn.Close();

       return container;
    }
    private SqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection retConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.MachineName + "; Initial Catalog=RESTAURANT; Integrated Security = TRUE");
        retConn.Open();
        return retConn;
    }
}
```

Actually dataset flushes all data it had got from (SELECT * FROM PRODITEM where PRODUCT_id = '1') and shows data from the last executed query i-e (select * from proditem where item_id = 1)
Any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is trying to run the command via `SqlCommand`.
that way you will have better knowledge on what you get back.
use this example:

```
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectCmd, conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader[0], reader[1]));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Always call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
```

and modify it so you'll return a table as you need.
the reason i offer you this is that it's easy to use and you get immediate debug information that help you understand sql mistakes

Comment: My mstake, i didnt provided the definition for 'getConnection()' thats why you are saying this. But now its there. Kindly review. And one thing more: I get expected data when I comment listBx_item.SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: i that so can you debug to see what's the wrong parameter u r sending to `showPrice` there?

Comment: I debugged the code and figured out that my second last query gets flushed before executing last query. Therefore, data of secondlast query gets lost and data for last query is retrived in list_item. :( And if i do not flush data from dataset then the result of both last 2 queries is retrieved in list_item